# How to upload file as attachment in javamail api?

Tags: java, email-attachments

Hi I am new to JavaMail .

I want to upload a file as an attachement. It stores only the filename.

File is successfully attached with the filename only and not content of that file.

How to solve it. Thanks in advance...

I have tried the following code:

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(toAddr));

        if (subject == null) {
            message.setSubject("");
        } else {
            message.setSubject(subject);
        }

        if (attachedFile == null || attachedFile.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            if (content == null) {
                message.setText("");
            } else {
                message.setText(content);
            }

        } else {
            // Create the message part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            if (content == null) {
                messageBodyPart.setText("");
            } else {
                messageBodyPart.setText(content);
            }

            // Create a multipar message
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            // Set text message part
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Part two is attachment
            // messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(
                    attachedFile.getBytes("UTF-8"),
                    "application/octet-stream");
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            // DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attchedFile);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachedFile);
            // messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "image/*");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            message.setContent(multipart);
        }

        Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: What have you tried and what error (if any) did you encounter? Post your code.

Comment: actually no error while attaching file. file is added with mail content. but content is not displayed properly and the file size is always 1k.

Comment: Here is a example. http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/javamail/how-to-send-an-email-with-a-file-attachment.html                                                Also please give a description of what you tried and sample code if there is any.

Answer (score 8):

```
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    messageBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/plain");

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // adds attachments


            MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();


            File file=new File("Z:/filename");

            try {

                attachPart.attachFile(file);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);

    // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
    message.setContent(multipart);
```

might be this will work

Answer (score 2):

```
 MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

 // create the message 
 MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

 //fill message to be sent
 messageBodyPart.setText("Hi hello try and send this message");

 Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
 multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

 //attach your file here
 messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
 DataSource source =  new FileDataSource(fileAttachment); // your file
 messageBodyPart.setDataHandler( new DataHandler(source));
 messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileAttachment);
 multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

 // Put message in parts
 message.setContent(multipart);


 Transport.send( message );
```

Comment: btw.. you have not mentioned, what problem are you facing... This works for me http://www.roseindia.net/javamail/SendAttachment.shtml